# Remove trailing zeroes from bytearray C#

Tags: c#

I have a code that writes byte[] to file using Marshal.Copy as shown below.
From what I observed while debugging, some of the values may contain zeroes within the byte array.

Example:

```
[0] 113
[1] 70
[2] 57
[3] 172
[4] 70
[5] 0
[6] 165
[7] 0
[8] 224
[9] 48
[10] 136
```

You can see byte[5] and byte[7] are zeroes.

The problem is while reading the byte[] back from memory. Existing code is as below.

Since  byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_DATA_SIZE] is initialzed with all zeroes. Existing code is trying to remove trailing. But in that processm, it it also removing zeroes within the byte[].

How can retain the zeroes within the byte[] but remove trailing zeroes ? as you can see in the code, while reading the data from memory, I do not know size.

Comment: I've found it best to prefix data in this sort of file with a header containing, at a minimum, the structure revision and data length. That helps to avoid a variety of problems. In your case, how do you handle valid data that happens to end with a zero? It also allows applications to check, via the structure revision, that the data is in a format they can handle. The application can upgrade old formats, or fail gracefully if it reads a file it cannot process, e.g. when either the data or application was restored from a backup.

Comment: @HABO This is the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25452343/467473), you *could* use Linq (darling child that it is). Or you could do it the simpler (and more obvious) way, which I'm willing to bet will outperform the Linq version.

You can perform an in-place "trim" by resizing it:

```
public static void TrimTrailingBytes( ref byte[] buffer , byte trimValue )
{
  int i = buffer.Length ;

  while ( i > 0 && buffer[--i] == trimValue )
  {
    ; // no-op by design
  }

  Array.Resize( ref buffer , i+1 ) ;

  return ;
}
```

Usage is easy:

```
byte[] foo = {0,1,0,2,0,3,0,0,0,0,} ;
TrimTrailingBytes( ref foo , 0 ) ;
```

producing the expected

```
{0,1,0,2,0,3,}
```

Or you can return a copy of the source array, trimmed to length:

```
static byte[] TrimTrailingBytes( byte[] buffer , byte trimValue )
{
  int i = buffer.Length ;

  while ( i > 0 && buffer[--i] == trimValue )
  {
    ; // no-op by design
  }

  byte[] resized = new byte[i+1] ;
  Array.Copy( buffer , resized , resized.Length ) ;

  return resized ;
}
```

Usage is equally simple:

```
byte[] foo = {0,1,0,2,0,3,0,0,0,0,} ;
byte[] bar = TrimTrailingBytes( foo , 0 ) ;
```

again producing the expected

```
{0,1,0,2,0,3,}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not as pretty as the LINQ solution, but it should be faster (I didn't bench, also depends on the size of your arrays) without reversing the array twice.

```
byte[] withZeroes = new byte[]{ 1,0,1,10,1,1,0,1,5,0,0,0,0,0 }; // Dummy

int indexOfLastNonZero = withZeroes.Length;
while(indexOfLastNonZero != 0 && withZeroes[indexOfLastNonZero-1] == 0)
    indexOfLastNonZero--;

byte[] withoutZeroes = new byte[indexOfLastNonZero];
Array.Copy(withZeroes, withoutZeroes, indexOfLastNonZero); 
// withoutZeroes: 1, 0, 1, 10, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5
```